# VCF file is missing mandatory header line ("#CHROM...")

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.6, vcftools

I am getting an error when I am going to read a VCF file using **scikit-allel** library inside a docker image and os ubuntu 18.04. It shows that

raise RuntimeError('VCF file is missing mandatory header line ("#CHROM...")')
RuntimeError: VCF file is missing mandatory header line ("#CHROM...")

But in the VCF file is well-formatted.

Here is my code of how I applied :

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import allel
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

GenomeVariantsInput = allel.read_vcf('quartet_variants_annotated.vcf', samples=['ISDBM322015'],fields=[ 'variants/CHROM', 'variants/ID', 'variants/REF',
 'variants/ALT','calldata/GT'])
```

version what Installed :
Python 3.6.9
Numpy 1.19.5
pandas 1.1.5
scikit-allel 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line like this in the first:

`#CHROM POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NA00001 NA00002 NA00003`

but it's not static for all of the files, you have to make a `Header` like above for your file. (I suggest try this header first and if it's got error then customize it)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did like that but still getting the same error